# How to apply a custom function between a vector and each the columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to calculate the proportionality phi between 2 dataframe comparing one column from the first dataframe against each column of the second dataframe. I'm just using matrices just for the example code.

```
mat.1<-matrix(rnorm(30),nrow = 10,ncol = 3)
colnames(mat.1)<-c("A","B","C")
mat.2<-matrix(rnorm(30),nrow = 10,ncol = 3)
colnames(mat.2)<-c("V1","V2","V3")
custom.correlation<-function(x,y){
  cor(x,y)
}
```

I would like to find a way to compute the correlations in a fashion like:

```
cust.corr(A,V1)
cust.corr(A,V2)
cust.corr(A,V3)
cust.corr(B,V1)
```

etc. etc. without using a loop.

My custom function is more complex and takes as input directly the 2 dataframes.
Thanks

Comment: In your example you have two matrices, but you describe having data frames. These are not the same thing. Which do you have?

Comment: I'm using data frames

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```r
name_df <- expand.grid(colnames(mat.1), colnames(mat.2))
f <- function(i) custom.correlation(mat.1[,i[1]], mat.2[,i[2]])
name_df$cor <- apply(name_df, 1, f)

name_df
#>   Var1 Var2         cor
#> 1    A   V1  0.43061855
#> 2    B   V1 -0.24786963
#> 3    C   V1 -0.44468358
#> 4    A   V2 -0.10678237
#> 5    B   V2  0.51727866
#> 6    C   V2  0.39317290
#> 7    A   V3 -0.31834670
#> 8    B   V3 -0.08776827
#> 9    C   V3 -0.19823759
```